# Do I need a license for adobe air app?

Tags: air, desktop

Do I need some sort of special license to distribute my adobe air app ? I know that if i want to redistribute the air runtime packed with my app i need to have a permision from adobe. But what about if i want to distribute just my air app without air runtime ? The user will install runtime on their own, i will just give them a link to adobe webiste.

Comment: please read the license related to air it will tell you the answer http://www.adobe.com/licensing/

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://www.adobe.com/special/products/air/runtime_distribution1.html) :

> - You do not need to sign the Adobe AIR Runtime Distribution License Agreement to have your website direct end users to Adobe.com in order to download the Adobe AIR runtime. Also, you do not need to sign the license agreement if you are using the Adobe AIR seamless install feature (via the install badge).

Concerning your app users :

> **Individual users**
>
> If you are an individual user who wants to download the Adobe AIR runtime for personal use, you do not need a distribution agreement. Instead, you should download the Adobe AIR runtime directly from Adobe's website and use it in accordance with the included software license agreement.